# How many different numbers with 6 digits are there that aren't divisible by 3 or 6 and don't contain 0

Tags: combinatorics

I need to get numbers with 6 digits that aren't divisible by 3 or 6 and don't contain 0 using combinatoric's formulas (not just count them using a script, but use equations).

There is my approach:

Using the formula of arrangements with repetitions I can count all 6 digits numbers that don't contain 0

```
N = n^k = 9^6 = 531 441‬
```

Then I need to count 6 digits numbers that are divisible by 3 and don't contain 0 (I don't need to count numbers that are divisible by 6 because the set of numbers that divisible by 3 already contains them, so it'll be extra work)  then subtract them from the overall count of numbers. But the problem is that I don't know how to count them. I tried to use the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2151365/721847), but my attempts fell apart. I have written a script to count the numbers, so I know that there are `177 146` 6 digits numbers that are divisible by 3 and don't contain 0.

Comment: Use inclusion exclusion. (Not div by 3) AND (Not div by 6) AND (Not contain zero). This will be equal to total - (count of union of above sets)

Comment: Sorry, maybe the question wasn't clear enough, but I need equations from combinatorics.

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion is most certainly an equation from combinatorics.

Comment: Yes, you`re right but I can't count 6 digits numbers that are divisible by 3 and don't contain 0. This's the main problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a number is divisible by $6$, it’s divisible by $3$, so it suffices to count numbers not divisible by 3 that don’t contain zeros. This is easy, since for any of the $9^5$ possibilities for the first five digits, there will be $3$ possibilities for the last digit, as exactly one integer of every three consecutive integers is divisible by $3$. Therefore, the number of possibilities is $3\cdot9^5=\boxed{177147}$.